# Taxonomy Rewrite Problem

Tags: taxonomy, rewrite-rules, query-variable

I have actor and genre taxonomies.

```
add_action('init','ap_url_redirect_rules');
add_filter('query_vars', 'ap_register_query_vars');
function ap_url_redirect_rules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)?$', 'index.php?actor=$matches[1]', 'top'); // .com/brad-pitt
    add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$', 'index.php?actor=$matches[1]&sort=$matches[2]', 'top'); // .com/brad-pitt/popular or new, etc.
    add_rewrite_rule('genre/([^&]+)?$', 'index.php?genre=$matches[1]', 'top'); // .com/genre/comedy
    add_rewrite_rule('genre/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$', 'index.php?genre=$matches[1]&sort=$matches[2]', 'top'); // .com/genre/popular or new, etc.
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
function ap_register_query_vars($query_vars){
    $query_vars[]='sort';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

I have this code. Actor rewrite rule is working but genre and single post (post link) not working (**404 Page Not Found**). What is my wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that `.com/genre/comedy` is actually picked up by the second rule since it matches that as well, and because it is added first I think it takes precedence.

You could try to swap the order, so it goes 3, 4, 1, 2.

For production, you might want to remove `flush_rewrite_rules();`, I believe it's quite expensive.